# My Html5/javascript does not display anything in chrome? What is the issue?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>HTML 5 Canvas</title>
<meta charset = "utf 8">
<script type = "text/javascript">
var canvasOne = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
</script>
</head>
<body>

<canvas id = "canvasOne" width = "500" height ="300">

context.fillStyle = "#ffffaa";
context.fillRect(0,0,500,300);

</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

It would be greatly appreciated if someone can post some working code in order for me to properly implement a "yellow filled canvas". Thanks

Comment: Maybe you forgot to wrap you JS between `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>HTML 5 Canvas</title>
<meta charset = "utf 8">
</head>
<body>

<canvas id = "canvasOne" width = "500" height ="300"></canvas>

<script>
var canvasOne = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
var context = canvasOne.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "#ffffaa";
context.fillRect(0,0,500,300);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're putting JavaScript instructions inside `<canvas>` rather than inside `<script>`.